# svn check out problem

Tags: ros, svn

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear Sir,
I use Ubuntu 16.04 and I want to check out the stack containing swissranger_camera using svn, but after running this code "svn co [https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/branches/trunk_cturtle/stacks/camera_drivers_experimental"](https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/branches/trunk_cturtle/stacks/camera_drivers_experimental%22), I got this error:
"svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/branches/trunk_cturtle/stacks/camera_drivers_experimental'
svn: E000111: Error running context: Connection refused"

I appreciate you to help me to solve the problem.
Thanks,
Abbas

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/245139/svn-check-out-problem/) by [Abbas](https://answers.ros.org/users/27800/abbas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-10-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

code.ros.org has been taken offline a long time ago. You'll need to look somewhere else for this code.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2016-10-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Abbas](https://answers.ros.org/users/27800/abbas/) on 2016-10-06**:
Dear Sir,
Thank you for your answer.

**Comment by [Abbas](https://answers.ros.org/users/27800/abbas/) on 2016-10-06**:
Do you know the address of a website that corrects the codes which contains code.ros.org?
Thanks